# What is the font used in Metro Sport?

Tags: font-identification

Can anyone tell me what this font is or which is similar?

[image]

Comment: Hey Victoria, welcome to GD.SE! It's best to tell us what you have tried so that we can help you. Also have you used a resource such as [what the font](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jenna.
I have tried that website but i can't find it :/

Answer (score 1):

It looks to be [Aachen Bold](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/letraset/aachen/) by Colin Brignall or [Neue Aachen Bold](http://www.fonts.com/font/itc/neue-aachen/bold) by Jim Wasco.

[image: Aachen Bold at 48pt.]
[image: Neue Aachen Bold at various sizes.]

It's probably one of those fonts just because they have the cyrillic support for the cyrillic characters above “MetroSport.” There is a chance that the font is a pirated copy where someone created an “italic” of Aachen but it looks more likely that they used the fake italic option in Illustrator or Photoshop since the vertical thicknesses in the MetroSport logotype look distorted.

I couldn't find an italic anywhere, and doubt that one was designed so this reaffirms my guess that the MetroSport logotype is a distorted faux-italic. If you're going to use Aachen I'd advise against “italicizing” since it wasn't designed this way.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a similar font

[image]
https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/flat-it/dharma-slab/e-heavy-italic/

Hope this is close enough for your purposes - hope somebody finds closer!

Comment: S did not match actually

Comment: the truth is, that i must do exactly the same but if i can find the font i will use dharma slab.
Thanks

Comment: close, but the bottom of the lowercase E is also different.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - I'll edit, hopefully somebody has better luck finding the font!